# The parameter of thread function on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I was testing with a thread function. But the program always feedback an error. I guess that the error probably have something to do with the argument of the thread function, but i've no idea how to fix it. Thx in advance! The code is like:

```
-(void) doSomething:(id)p
{
   if((int)p == 100)
      NSLog(@"100");
   else
      NSLog(@"101");
}

int a = 100;
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doSomething:) withObject:a];
```

Comment: keep in mind: cocos2d is not thread safe and likely to crash if you access or modify nodes in a background thread

Answer (score 3):

Please read the docs for `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`. `a` isn't an object, it's a primitive type.

You need to wrap the value in an `NSNumber`.

```
-(void) doSomething:(NSNumber *)p
{
   if([p intValue] == 100)
      NSLog(@"100");
   else
      NSLog(@"101");
}

int a = 100;
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doSomething:) withObject:@(a)];
```

Or you can use GCD:

```
-(void) doSomething:(int)p
{
   if(p == 100)
      NSLog(@"100");
   else
      NSLog(@"101");
}

int a = 100;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self doSomething:a];
});
```

Comment: If you're not familiar with the new boxing notation and you are confused as to how Maddy's answer "wraps the value in NSNumber", the `@(a)` is syntactic sugar for `[NSNumber numberWithInt: a]`.

Answer (score 2):

you should do something like

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doSomething:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:a]];
```

as withObject takes only object and int is primitive datatype.

Comment: Doesn't need of this answer @rmaddy provide more than enough information.

Comment: They're only about a minute and a half apart, @Reformer; they probably started working on their answers at around the same time.

Comment: @Reformer it's not illegal to post an answer that essentially duplicates another answer.  The combination of two answers might lead to a better understanding.